# Moderator Election Coming Soon

Tags: discussion, election, moderation, graduation

I'm happy to announced that this site has been cleared for graduation… congratulations!

Unfortunately, there has been a long backlog of sites waiting for their custom site design, so rather than waiting for that backlog to clear, we are going to start moving ahead and hold the first community-based election of moderators sooner rather than later.

This is just a heads up to let you know why we're having the election before the graduation and design is ready. The election should start sometime in the next week or so, so watch the announcements on the sidebar for the notice.

Congratulations again… and enjoy!

Comment: @Yes No, just the election. Everything else will happen with the design.

Comment: Are you aware of or able to release an approximate timeline?

Comment: I have nothing to say but i'll just put a comment on this great announcement  : )

Comment: We already have some custom themes that might contribute to giving us out custom site.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Unfortunately with this backlog, sending a site to the "graduation queue" and getting a design published are currently two different things. We recently hired some fantastic new designers to help clear the backlog, but there is a still about 9 sites waiting for a design, so anything I can report here would be wildly inaccurate and subject to change, Designers are working on getting these design out amidst all the bug reports and feature requests, so which sites are completed first simply depends on who is available. Sorry I don't have anything further to report.

Comment: So great to see we made it! Hope to see our new look soon and that our [suggestions](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/610/3127) will be taken into account.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I understand, and sort of expected that would be the case. We will be eagerly waiting :)

Comment: So the moderator elections will be running while the site is still in Beta? Weird - but AWESOME!!!!

Comment: So how do you achieve moderator anyway>?

Comment: You have to run during the election and meet requirements. Voting will then occur, and the users will pick the moderators. Generally voting occurs once per year, just so that if a mediocre mod gets elected, they can be switched.