# Moderator Campaign 2020

Tags: discussion, moderation

Since the mass moderators resignation last January [David♦](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2690) and [iKlsR♦](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2691) relinquished their duties, leaving us currently with only two active moderators, [Gandalf](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/599/gandalf3) and [Duarte](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/19307/duarte-farrajota-ramos).

With the constant efforts of the community and tireless help from a bunch of very active users we have managed to keep the site barely in working order, but other that handling flags and doing regular basic maintenance work, that leaves us with little time and energy for much more.

We decided to have a moderator election in the near future, and would love to scan for potential candidates. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where no one would apply or candidates would be unaware of the event, we are campaigning in anticipation of the actual election, as "publicity" for the actual application phase.

Many people are reluctant about the role but it [need not be a a lot of work, nor an arduous task](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/702), in fact most of the tasks you already take on as regular users are the same as those of moderators, which helps lift the burden of actual official ones.

There are a few regular users of this site that know the community well, the ins-and-outs of this site, and would definitely make a very fine upcoming moderators. We would definitely love having them as colleagues in this task.

If you are interested or available to becoming one please post an answer below or leave a comment. We'd love to hear from all.

Comment: Okay then :). Since I'm not a good candidate for a moderator, I'd love to hear what can regular users do to help moderators carry the load. I'm currently just flagging dupes, but is there something that makes more sense? :)

Comment: As regular user you are probably limited by the system itself on how much you can help. If i recall correctly there is a limit on how many items in a certain queue you can review, flags can also only be handled by mods. Maybe you would make for good candidate. Why don't you try running, there nothing to loose ;). You may be relatively new to the site, but you've shown quite a lot of dedication so far. I'm also quite new and inexperienced as a mod myself, compared to other mods that were all here since the inception of the site.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know if I'll have the time required for this commitment, so I won't be joining as candidate.

Comment: @RobertGützkow while a present moderator is always better than an absent one, there are no established participation quotas or hard set hours you must put in. Your application would still be welcome

Comment: Great idea! If I could I would nominate *Ray Mairlot*, *susu* and *batFINGER*, they all trying to keep the site organized anyway so... *Ray*, *susu*, *batFINGER* - What do you think?

Comment: They would also be among my potential candidates, unfortunately Ray has specifically declined it, and Batfinger has not responded so far.

Comment: Since Jachym withdrew I changed my mind and joined as a candidate. I still don't have much time to spend, but I thought it might still be a good idea to have another person to choose from.

Comment: @RobertGützkow You did well, glad to see you running.

Answer (score 3):

Cue the drums...

> Today I'm announcing my candidacy for a **moderator of Blender Stack Exchange**
> (With Suzanne the Monkey as my running mate)

### That's right

1. We all benefit from this site, it'd be nice to give something back :)
2. Duarte and Gandalf probably need some sleep
3. After a year on the site I know enough to be of help

Plus, I really enjoy making stuff organized, so that's a bonus for me :).

### We Promise:

<sup>(Sorry, I can't keep anything serious)</sup>

1. Full transparency
   [image]
2. BlenderCare for All
   [image]
3. Protection of traditional (and clipped) values
   [image]

<sup>This message was approved by APPLE PIES FOR SUZANNE LLC.</sup>

<sup>(Yeah and I'd definitely show you my previous experience, but it's under audit right now...)</sup>

Comment: I knew you would not resist! Glad to see you running :)

Comment: Thanks :). I wouldn't go for it without your encouragement.

Comment: +1 You have my support.

Comment: Thank you @RobertGützkow, you just made my day :).