# Is this SE running communtiy promotion ads?

Tags: support, feature-request

I recently made a new area51 proposal and i heard about some SEs
 running community promotion ads like:(see the links)
[http://physics.stackexchange.com](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015)
[http://earthscience.stackexchange.com](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/community-promotion-ad)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

As of September 10, 2015 we are starting the community ads.

[Community Promotion Ads - 2015](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/880/2217)

---

Old answer for the beta site below.

---

TL;DR
**Nope**

---

Beta sites on the SE network do [not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237283/278094) get community ads, only full sites.

> In response to the popularity of that program, we've extended this vote based advertising program to all the public Stack Exchange sites.

From [Community Promotion Ads](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/)

When we graduate (we are in the [process](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/700/2217) [now](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/782/2217)) then we will get ads. (How often do you see people asking *for* ads?)