# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As your site is undergoing our new design-independent graduation process, you'll be enjoying your own run of design-independent Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting Blender addons, tutorials, and other resources
- relevant events, conferences, or meetups
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 40 KB
- If the background of the image is white, there must be a 1x1 border of not-white at the edges of the ad

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/880).

Answer (score 11):

[image: Blend-Exchange!]

Comment: Support [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), the free long-term .blend hosting site. This ad will show new users where they can upload .blend files.

Comment: Resolution is not an issue, see here: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884

Comment: "If the background of the image is white, there must be a 1x1 border of not-white at the edges of the ad" --- so #fefefe  ?  :)

Comment: @zeffii Fixed, borders have been added

Comment: @zeffii For the record, [I voted for #fafafa](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24047379#24047379) :P.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Download blender]

Comment: Is the gradient necessary? I think plain white would be nicer and more in-keep with the site look.

Comment: I guess not, but I tried a few different things, and plain white looked too, well plain. I do agree that it looks a little dark, will lighten it up.

Comment: @David maybe just a background similar to the twitter add? I personally think that would look best.

Comment: For some reason the alignment of the blender logo bugs me.. What about shifting it over (like [this](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/92971))?

Comment: I don't know exactly what, but something about "get the program" seems a little odd, kind of blunt if you know what I mean.  I definitely think we should advertise blender.org, but maybe someone could think of a little more "suave" way of putting it. :)

Answer (score 6):

[image: 3D graphics!]

Comment: Maybe you need to use Real flow for a fluid sim, or 3DS max for a job! Either way you will need SE quality resource that has all the answers you need. Make this a reality! Join the proposal now (We also need sample questions).

Comment: Why the down votes? This is perfectly relevant to this site, and may be helpful for Blender users who also use other commercial packages in their workflow. Besides, there is no official place on stack exchange for Max, Maya, Modo, and Zbrush quetions. Why not add the missing Q&A site?

Comment: By the way, this won't be representing our site on other site. This will be appearing on the margins of *this* site, ad is to gain support for this Area51 proposed site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics-modeling-animation?referrer=4bIZIhmQJeWKQcyqcR7pKw2

Comment: Final note: We are graduating. If anyone is afraid this site will consume us and get merged with us, fear not, the chances are *low*

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this ad. If it is to gain support for a new site, why does it say 'Learn to Model and Texture'? I also don't think it's clear that '3D Graphics' is the name of a proposed stack site.

Comment: @RayMairlot This was originally made for other sites and was (lazily) ported here. AFA learn to model and texture, the idea was for people on other art sites (GD etc.) to get involved so they can learn to model and texture (they all wan't to get around to it someday). If you have a suggestion for a better add, you can contact me [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm). Use "@GiantCowFilms" to ping me.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 1):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Lacks a call to action. What will happen when I click on it???? Maybe some text saying download....?

Answer (score -4):

## You have the *tools* to make 3D art. Now get your *answers*.

blender.stackexchange.com

---

If you guys like this catch copy, or some variation of it, go ahead and vote / suggest improvements. Next step will be to come up with an image.

Comment: Please don't use the answer space in this thread to solicit help for ad design / copy review. Also, keep in mind that this thread is solely for ads that will show up on your own site - advertising your own site on your own site is probably less than productive.

Comment: Huh? I'm not soliciting help for anything, just inviting community feedback. "Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar." Isn't the purpose of this post to come up with ads for advertising blender.stackexchange.com to people browsing other sites on the StackExchange network? That's the impression I got. I guess I don't understand how StackExchange's ads work or what the real purpose of this is. So "Community Promotion Ads" are NOT ads for the purpose of promoting the Blender Stack Exchange community?

Comment: No, in this context, "main site" is blender.stackexchange.com (since we are on the "meta site"). It's for ads to promote to the people already on your site. Show folks who are interested in your subject matter things that they would be further interested in that isn't necessarily on the network or even related to the network.

Comment: @Mentalist Also, please retract any Down Votes to adds you don't think represent our site, since they represent other sites ;D thanks.

Comment: @GraceNote Thanks for explaining. So would I for example post an ad for CG Cookie, or Blend Swap if I thought members here may like those sites? Seems odd to me since ads are usually paid for - couldn't anyone trying to promote their own Blender-related site come over to SE trying to get free promotion? Or are we all okay with that as long as something gets enough upvotes? (I have not voted on any of the ads posted here yet.)